# Python compare list to list of lists to check for duplicates

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm trying to update a CSV file by loading it in and then checking it against an existing list of lists. The data is read in like this by using csv.reader:

```
[["Name","URL","Team"],["Name","URL","Team"]]
```

I have another list of lists in the same format:

```
[["Name","URL","Team"],["Name","URL","Team"]]
```

My goal is to only add what doesn't already exist in the CSV file (first list of lists). I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
reader = csv.reader(file)
fantasyList = [["Name","URL","Team"],["Name","URL","Team"]] 

new_list = []

for elem in reader:
    if elem not in new_list:
        new_list.append(elem)

for elem in fantasyList:
    if elem not in new_list:
        new_list.append(elem)
```

So how can I add a list from a list of lists to a separate list of lists without duplicating entries?

**

### CLARIFICATION BELOW

**

Here is my problem:

I have a list of lists. It's a list which contains lists. Here's an example:

```
[["Bob the Builder", "Google", "Free Breakfast"],
["I down vote because I'm better than you", "Actually dude, your question kinda blows. Just clean it up and we'll upvote it.", "Is this better? because I Dunno LOL ¯\(°_o)/¯"]]
```

If that isn't clear enough, check out [data structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) for a better explanation of what is a "list" in python. So now that you understand what a list is, imagine putting a list inside of another list, and then repeating the process by adding more lists to the master list. You'd end up with a "list of lists."

Now lets say I have a [CSV file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) that I want to load into my python program. The easy way to do so is to use the `csv` module. Here is the [CSV module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). Here's an example of how to load a CSV file:

```
import csv

f = open(r'foo/bar.csv', 'a+')

reader = csv.reader(f)
```

So the above code demonstrates how to load a CSV as a reader object. Here is an example of how to iterate over the rows of the CSV:

```
import csv

f = open(r'foo/bar.csv', 'r')

reader = csv.reader(f)

for row in reader:
     print row
```

The above demonstrates how to print all of the rows of your CSV. So now imagine a CSV that has three columns. When you load the CSV using the `csv` module, you get a reader object. Lets say you want to update this CSV by adding rows that don't already exist. We don't want to create duplicate entries in our CSV file. So lets go ahead and take a look at what should, in theory, work:

```
import csv

f = open(r'foo/bar.csv', 'r')
#initialize a temporary list to transfer the CSV contents to 
tempList = []

#initialize the final list to be saved to the CSV
finalList =[]

reader = csv.reader(f)

for row in reader:
     tempList.append(row)

#close the file to avoid read/write errors
f.close()
```

Okay, good. Now our `tempList` should be a "list of lists" (see above examples) which represents the three columns of each row of the CSV. So now lets take a look at our other "list of lists" which we want to join with our `tempList`:

```
fantasyList = [["Pushing Will Protect You","Shoving Will Protect you", "Do you have stairs in your house?"],["Pak","Chooi","Unf"]]
```

As you can see, the above demonstrates a "list of lists." Now consider the following code:

```
#For each list in tempList, check if it exists in the final list

for elem in tempList:
    if elem not in finalList:
        finalList.append(elem)

for elem in fantasyList:
    if elem not in finalList:
        finalList.append(elem)
```

The above code should not create any duplicate entries in our `finalList`. For example, lets say `tempList` contains the list `["Pak","Chooi","Unf"]`. Now lets say `fantasyList` also contains `["Pak","Chooi","Unf"]`. After the above is run, `finalList` should not contain two entries of `["Pak","Chooi","Unf"]` . So then the final step to update our CSV is to write our `finalList` to file:

```
f = open(r'foo/bar.csv', 'w')

wr = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')

wr.writerows(finalList)

f.close()
```

But herein lies my problem: I find duplicate entries in my CSV. For whatever reason, I cannot figure out what isn't working here.

Comment: But what doesn't work? You get errors or incorrect results?

Comment: It doesn't recognize duplicate entries and new_list contains both lists.

Comment: Don't see a reason why it won't work. Could you provide example content of the csv file and more complete code. The `CSV List` does not relate to you code. Difficult to tell what is happening.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it any better. It's simply that I have two lists of lists and I need to join them without any duplication.

Comment: How is `fantasyList` populated? Is order important?

Comment: Also, I agreed with @Marcin , your code should work, so there is something else going on here we can't see.

Comment: fantasyList is populated using fantasyList.append(["Name","URL","Team"]) and therefore becomes a list of lists. Order isn't really important except for the fact that column one is "Name", column two is "URL" and column three is "Team"

Comment: It just occurred to me. Is it a problem that I'm using csv.reader? Do I have to convert the object to something else to make the comparisons?

Comment: We can't tell where the problem is, as this isn't complete code. This code would break on this line `for elem in fantasyList` as in *this code* there is no `fantasyList` to iterate over. **Show us more of your code.**

Comment: Okay I tried to better represent what `fantasyList` represents. I can't really include more code because it just isn't related and wouldn't make sense to include. Again, it's just a list of lists that I want to compare to another list of lists and merge together without creating duplicate entries.

Comment: @Jester87 You've edited the question, but you didn't address what was asked in the comments: A complete code and csv that exhibits the problem you're having. People looked at your code, and said that it should work; That is, the problem is probably somewhere else, and you didn't actually test the snippet that you posted. If you make a csv with "Name,URL,Team", your original snippet does what you want. Ie. we do not see the problem.

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo Fair enough. I'm not going to release my code nor my csv because they contain copyrighted materials. I guess the only thing I can gather then is something isn't working somewhere else if you and everyone else insist that the above should work.

Comment: @Jester87 I didn't mean you should share your (possibly large) real data and code. You should try to reduce the code and data to the smallest case that still fails. The code you had before the "clarification" would've been enough if it still had the bug (plus maybe an "import csv" at the beginning). But it's hard to test if you don't give data that produces the bug, so you could've included a csv that just had some random data like `a,b,c` `a,b,c` `d,e,f` that was enough to reproduce the problem. And you should always test that your snippet and accompanying test data still exhibits the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the actual problem is with your code, because its not clear from the snippets you provided.

However, here is an alternate solution to your problem.  Create a `set()` which will enforce uniqueness of items. This way it doesn't matter what your adding, only unique things will get added to the master set.

Here is a small example:

```
>>> first = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
>>> second = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],[1,2,3],['g','h','i']]
>>> master = set(tuple(i) for i in first)
>>> master.update((tuple(i) for i in second))
>>> list(master)
[('g', 'h', 'i'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), (1, 2, 3)]
```

As you may have noticed, sets are not ordered; if this becomes an issue you can always order the set later by converting it to a list and then run `sorted` on it.

The second thing you may have noticed is that you end up with a list of *tuples* (sets can only contain hashable types).  This won't have much impact if all you are doing is writing the combined file back out.

The other way to do this is with list comprehensions:

```
>>> master = [i for i in second if i not in first] + first
>>> master
[[1, 2, 3], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Comment: This is a fantastic solution. I appreciate you taking the time to help. Thank you!